# overriding application.property file after command of dspring.config.loc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have application.property file inside resource folder with some properties in my project. I am trying to override that through command line `dspring.config.locationt=//external file location` but it's not overriding - why?

Here I am using the values of property file in my java code

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
@Component
public class ApplicationProperties {

    @Value("${twilio.accont_sid}")
    private String twilioAccountSID;  

    @Value("${twilio.auth_token}")
   private String twilioAuthToken;

    @Value("${twilio.from.mobile}")
    private String twilioFromMobile; 

    so on............
}
```

I want property file should override, after providing external property file location configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can set this variable in your IDE or add to your command when running jar.file

```
-Dspring.config.location=file://external_conf.properties
```

Comment: i  have more variables we cant type and pass...and